# Is it possible to hit a breakpoint set in a javascript file with visual studio while using Firefox?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I tried setting a breakpoint in visual studio in a JavaScript file and i get a message when i hover on the breakpoint, which is:

**"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The document is not loaded."**

I am using firefox. Is it possible to hit the breakpoint and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; Visual Studio's Javascript debugger only supports IE.

You should use the Javascript debugger in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).

Comment: Thanks - this is the definitive answer for all the questions out there that don't specify what browser is being used.  A case of needing to know the right question to ask.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Javascript Debugging in Visual Studio hooks in to the IE Script engine to hit breakpoints. As far as I know, there's no Firefox extension to allow VS to hook in to Mozilla's Javascript Engine.

You could always download [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), set breakpoints there, and debug Javascript using that.

Answer (score 1):

No ... for firefox debugging of javascript, use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)